# VirtualBox - screen resolution wont resize

Tags: linux, virtualbox, resolution

Already installed guest additions. Resolution options are greyed-out, it is stuck in 800x600.
Auto-resize option is also greyed-out.
Host is Windows 7, guest is Linux Mint (Ubuntu). Tried OpenSuse earlier and got the same problem.
Also tried to install Nvidia driver inside the guest, but installation failed due to being a VM.

Searched the entire day for a solution, and found none. I need the VM to run a Cardano node, but in 800x600 I cant do anything.

Comment: I am not sure (Working in Kali inside VMware at good resolution). Shut down the guest, restart Windows 7, reinstall Virtual Box, restart the Guest machine. If that does not work consider trying VMware Player trial version.

Comment: VMware requires windows 8 or above.

Comment: If you wish to use Kali, you will need to modernize your systems.

Comment: Solved the problem after resintalling VirtualBox and Mint. This time I was able to change the resolution through the guest system. The options in VirtualBox are still greyed-out.

Comment: That is primarily what I posted at the beginning, so I posted an answer for you that you may wish to acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the resolution problem (remember this is older equipment), try the following.

Shut down the guest, restart Windows 7, reinstall Virtual Box, restart the Guest machine.

You may also wish to reinstall the guest after the above.